# Django channels, disconnect

Tags: django, django-channels

I have my WebSockets working with django channels. The last thing I'd like to do is close the socket if a user clicks a button, so in the frontend, I just send a disconnect message to the server:

`socket.send({action: 'disconnect'`});

Then, in my consumer, I simply disconnect:

```
async def receive(self, text_data):
    text_data_json = json.loads(text_data)
    if 'action' in text_data_json and text_data_json['action'] == 'disconnect':
        await self.disconnect(0)


async def disconnect(self, close_code):
    await self.channel_layer.group_discard(
        self.room_group_name,
        self.channel_name
    )
```

Why is my WebSocket not disconnecting properly? (I still receive messages)

Answer (score 4):

```
async def receive(self, text_data):
    text_data_json = json.loads(text_data)
    if 'action' in text_data_json and text_data_json['action'] == 'disconnect':
        return await self.close()
```

you can also try this. You may also include a close code if required.

Answer (score 2):

```
def disconnect(self, close_code):
    # Leave room group
    async_to_sync(self.channel_layer.group_discard)(
        self.room_group_name,
        self.channel_name
    )
```

Try this

Comment: I refresh the page. it calls the disconnect. I do this. but the refreshed page receive the same message twice. the old one is not discarded!?